# Sorting Custom UITableViewCells (Swift 2, Xcode 7)

Tags: sorting, swift2, xcode7, uitableview

Trying to create an app that sorts posts by user "up vote" like Reddit.

Been searching around trying to figure out how I can sort my cells by the number of "votes" (an Int value) that the post has.

In the view controller where the posts are displayed, I think that most of this is relevant. I've also got a search bar in the view that is in play here as well.

When run with the below code, nothing shows up in my view controller.

Any help would be much appreciated

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var posts = [Post]()
static var imageCache = NSCache()
var inSearchMode = false
var filteredVenues = [Post]()
var sortByVotes = [Post]()

private var _post: Post?

var post: Post? {
    return _post
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done 

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 368

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot.value)

        self.sortByVotes = []

        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshots {

                print("SNAP: \(snap)")

                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    let key = snap.key
                    let post = Post(postKey: key, dictionary: postDict)
                    self.sortByVotes.append(post)
                }
            }

        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if inSearchMode {
        return filteredVenues.count
    }

    return sortByVotes.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //let post = posts[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as? PostCell {

        cell.request?.cancel()

        var img: UIImage?

        let post: Post!

        posts = posts.sort{$0.votes > ($1.votes)} // added this*****


        if inSearchMode {
            post = filteredVenues[indexPath.row]

        } else {
            post = sortByVotes[indexPath.row]
        }

        if let url = post.imageUrl {
            img = FeedVC.imageCache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage
        }

        cell.configureCell(post, img: img)

        return cell

    } else {

        return PostCell()
    }


}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let post = sortByVotes[indexPath.row]

    if post.imageUrl == nil {
        return 200
    } else {

        return tableView.estimatedRowHeight
    }
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        inSearchMode = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        posts = posts.sort{$0.votes > ($1.votes)} //added this ***
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true
        let lower = searchBar.text!.lowercaseString
        filteredVenues = sortByVotes.filter({$0.venueName!.rangeOfString(lower) != nil})
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func sortPosts(){ //removed this function******

    sortByVotes = posts.sort { $0.votes > ($1.votes)}
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: are you calling the `func sortPosts()`anywhere?

Comment: Hey Victor, I ended up removing that function and added `posts = posts.sort{$0.votes > ($1.votes)}` in the `textDidChange` function and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, see above

Comment: But is it working now?

Comment: Yupp, everything seems to be working now

Comment: Yes, then the issue was what i said in the first comment. You were not calling this function so now that is directly in place it works too. Good to know it works.

Comment: Yeah, your comment was definitely helpful to identify the issue. I wasn't sure the best way to call that function though so I just ended up doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

So as you already realized the issue was that the function where the cells were sorted was not called. I know you moved the whole sorting code into the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but will be more maintainable and easier to reuse if you bring it back to a function and call it all times you want without repeating code.

It would look like this:

```
func sortPosts(){  //as you already did

    sortByVotes = posts.sort { $0.votes > ($1.votes)}
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and the following line to call the sort function where you are currently sorting the cells:

```
self.sortPosts();
```